# How to execute system command with an argument that contains spaces

Tags: shell

I'm creating a program that calls upon a previous program I created. To execute the previous program, i'm using a built in function called system. It works great but I'm coming across issues when trying to execute the system command with spaces in one of my arguments. It considers it to be another argument. May I ask how do I execute system command with an argument that contains spaces?

Execute Command `ArgumentProgram.exe`

Argument 1 `User`

Argument 2 `File 1`

Argument 3 `Open`

```
Program 1
int main()
{
    int status = system("ArgumentProgram.exe User1 File 1 Open");
    return 0;
}

Program 2(ArgumentProgram.exe)

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        printf( "This executable needs 3 parameters input");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("User name is :%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("File name is :%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Command is :%s\n", argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a matter of the C programming language, but how your platform executes commands with `system`. Typically this is a shell. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although depending on the operating system, my first guess is: Surround the argument by quotes like this:

```c
int status = system("ArgumentProgram.exe User1 \"File 1\" Open");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a bit risky to use `system` in C, because this might or might not involve the invocation of an aditional shell process in between. You are safer to pass program and arguments separately.

Alternative solutions depend on your runtime environment; see [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132) for implementation for Windows and for The Rest Of The World.

You might argue that by following this way, you would loosing standard compliance, and if you want to make portable accross platforms, you would have to provide via `#ifdef` one version for Windows and one for other operating system. However, even when using `system(....)`, you are only "portable" to the extent that your program conforms to ANSI C; but since the shell which is executed by *system*, and hence the interpretation of the command string, depends on your environment, you are not really portable either.